# Express.JS + MongoDB is calling route repeatedly with seemingly random values

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to code a receipt route that grabs receipts by their ID and then renders them to the page.

My route with MongoDB:

```
app.get('/receipt/:transactionId', (req,res) => {
    var transactionId = req.params.transactionId;
    console.log('TRANSACTION ID: ' + transactionId);

    SquareTransactionDB.findOne({_id: transactionId})
    .then((transaction) => {
        console.log('FOUND A TRANSACTION');
        res.render('receipt.hbs', {
            chargeList: transaction.receipt_list,
            date: transaction.created_on,
            transactionId
        });
        return;
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    })
});
```

What I get as a result is an infinitely waiting web-page, and these errors being thrown in Node terminal:

[image]

As soon as I Ctrl+C cancel the server, the page renders. Otherwise, the page just waits for a response.

How is it possible that my code is being called with 'bootstrap.css', or any other value for that matter? What can I do to fix this? I'm on hour 4 and have come to the conclusion that I cannot answer this alone.

I can resolve the page load - with the error still occurring server-side - if I add next() within the catch(e) block.

I appreciate any feedback.

Michael

***UPDATE***: By adding path '/bootstrap.css' instead of 'bootstrap.css' into my handlebars file, this error stopped getting thrown. Still does not answer my question as to why my style sheet was being used as an argument in parameters - seemingly without purpose.

Comment: Why are you using ` return;` in then( ). It is unnecessary

Comment: From what I understand, somehow a second request was being made `app.get('/receipt/bootstrap.css'`. Probably wrong bootstrap path was causing issue with handlebars